# file permission when executed by root

Tags: shell, unix, root, file-permissions

I have a script which is owned by a user and have read, write, execute permissions only for that user. The script outputs a log file.

If that file is executed by root, what will be permissions for the output log file.? who will be the owner of the log file in this case and what permissions /which user's umask will the log file acquire?

Comment: Why not just test it? Did you test it? What was the result?

Comment: i dont have the root user to test..

Comment: "sudo su -c umask" to find umask for root. That will tell you what permissions the file will have.

Comment: so will it acquire the umask of the executing user?